# Converting 2d array into 3d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Sorry for asking this question,if it is asked already, but in my case I have a special matrix of size 3000000x50 that I want to split it into 300 matrices of size 10000x50. I tried this but it is not working

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>data=np.random.randn(3000000,50)
>>>D=np.matrix.conjugate(data)
>>>ts=50
>>>ts=int(ts)       #number of time series that we have from our data
>>>lw=1e4
>>>lw=int(lw)    #length of each window 
>>>l=len(data)/lw   #l is number of windows
>>>l=np.floor(l)
>>>l=int(l)
#Dc is used to seperate each time series in l windows
>>>Dc=np.zeros((l,lw,ts))
>>>for i in range(l):
    Dc[i][0:lw-1][0:ts-1]=D[(lw)*(i):(lw*(i+1))-1][0:ts-1]
```

Comment: Why you just don't use `np.split()` : `new_array=np.split(D,300)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your initial array is correctly sorted and you want to split the array in 300 matrix "boxes", you can just need the following redefinition of the marix

```
import numpy as np
data = np.random.randn(3000000,50)
newData = data.reshape(300,10000,50) # This is as [300,10000,50] array

print newData[0,...] # Show the first matrix, 1 of 300
```

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [`np.vsplit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vsplit.html)(*Split an array into multiple sub-arrays vertically (row-wise)*) -

```
np.vsplit(data,300)
```

Sample run -

```
In [56]: data
Out[56]: 
array([[ 0.46677419,  0.07402051,  0.87270029,  0.12481164],
       [ 0.40789713,  0.36018843,  0.41731607,  0.17348898],
       [ 0.4701256 ,  0.10056201,  0.31289602,  0.18681709],
       [ 0.52407036,  0.89913995,  0.59097535,  0.38376443],
       [ 0.06734662,  0.24470334,  0.09523911,  0.35680219],
       [ 0.91178257,  0.58710922,  0.75099017,  0.24929987]])

In [57]: np.vsplit(data,3)
Out[57]: 
[array([[ 0.46677419,  0.07402051,  0.87270029,  0.12481164],
        [ 0.40789713,  0.36018843,  0.41731607,  0.17348898]]),
 array([[ 0.4701256 ,  0.10056201,  0.31289602,  0.18681709],
        [ 0.52407036,  0.89913995,  0.59097535,  0.38376443]]),
 array([[ 0.06734662,  0.24470334,  0.09523911,  0.35680219],
        [ 0.91178257,  0.58710922,  0.75099017,  0.24929987]])]
```

---

Depending on how you are going to use the output, you can just reshape the 2D input array into a 3D array that is of length `300` along the first axis, which must be much more efficient in terms of performance and memory. Memorywise it must be free as `reshaping` creates just a view of the numpy array. The implementation would be -

```
data.reshape(300,-1,data.shape[1])
```

Sample run -

```
In [68]: data
Out[68]: 
array([[ 0.46677419,  0.07402051,  0.87270029,  0.12481164],
       [ 0.40789713,  0.36018843,  0.41731607,  0.17348898],
       [ 0.4701256 ,  0.10056201,  0.31289602,  0.18681709],
       [ 0.52407036,  0.89913995,  0.59097535,  0.38376443],
       [ 0.06734662,  0.24470334,  0.09523911,  0.35680219],
       [ 0.91178257,  0.58710922,  0.75099017,  0.24929987]])

In [69]: data.reshape(3,-1,data.shape[1])
Out[69]: 
array([[[ 0.46677419,  0.07402051,  0.87270029,  0.12481164],
        [ 0.40789713,  0.36018843,  0.41731607,  0.17348898]],

       [[ 0.4701256 ,  0.10056201,  0.31289602,  0.18681709],
        [ 0.52407036,  0.89913995,  0.59097535,  0.38376443]],

       [[ 0.06734662,  0.24470334,  0.09523911,  0.35680219],
        [ 0.91178257,  0.58710922,  0.75099017,  0.24929987]]])
```

Here's some runtime tests to check for performance comparing actually splitting versus reshaping -

```
In [72]: data = np.random.rand(6000,40)

In [73]: %timeit np.vsplit(data,300)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.05 ms per loop

In [74]: %timeit data.reshape(300,-1,data.shape[1])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.08 µs per loop
```

Comment: Readers please use the `reshape` part not `(v)split`!

Comment: @askewchan Couldn't agree more on that!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It helped me a lot. The comparing test was very helpful.

Comment: vsplit requires an even split with no remainder. all subsplits must be equally sized